# Kivy Graphs from matplotlib not plotting the right size

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I created a Kivy app that is supposed to output the following:
Row 1 (Spans across 3 columns): A graph of candlegraph
Row 2 (3 columns): 1 graph in each column

The graphs update itself once every few seconds. I have only implemented code for the graph for row 1 and row 2 column 1. The code is shown below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class TestScreen(Widget):
    TestNum = NumericProperty(0)
    TestArray = ListProperty()


class Graph_Item(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)


class AppLayoutTest(App):
    def build(self):
        # update graph every 10 seconds        
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.mainExecutable(), 10)
        return TestScreen()

    def PlotCandlegraph(self, Data):
        plt.clf()
        for x in range(len(Data['Close'])):
            thickHeight = abs(Data['Close'][x] - Data['Open'][x])
            thinHeight = abs(Data['High'][x] - Data['Low'][x])
            thinBottom = Data['Low'][x]
            if Data['Close'][x] > Data['Open'][x]:
                thickBottom = Data['Open'][x]
                candleColor = 'green'
            else:
                thickBottom = Data['Close'][x]
                candleColor = 'red'

            plt.bar(x=Data.index[x], height=thickHeight, width=0.005, bottom=thickBottom, color=candleColor)
            plt.bar(x=Data.index[x], height=thinHeight, width=0.002, bottom=thinBottom, color=candleColor)

        plt.grid(True)
        plt.title("Candlegraph")
        graph = self.root.ids.Candlegraph
        graph.figure = plt.gcf()
        graph.draw()

    def mainExecutable(self):
        # input from somewhere else
        self.PlotCandlegraph(Data=RawData)
        self.TestPlot()

    def TestPlot(self):
        self.root.TestNum += 1
        self.root.TestArray.append(self.root.TestNum)

        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(self.root.TestArray, color='r')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.title("Test Graph")
        graph = self.root.ids.LossGraph
        graph.figure = plt.gcf()
        graph.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AppLayoutTest().run()
```

The kv file is shown here:

```
<TestScreen>
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size: root.width, root.height

        Graph_Item:
            id: Candlegraph

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Graph_Item:
                id: LossGraph

            Label:
                text: "RewardGraph"

            Label:
                text: "Information"
```

This is the result on the first cycle of the code:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsC9t.png)

Am I using the libary wrong? Is there a way to keep the graph at a certain size that spans across however many columns?

When I remove the plot from the second row by replacing the graph with a label instead, the following is shown and does not get squished however many cycle it runs:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oT0Y.png)

I also tried defining the size of the plots using the matplotlib library's plt.figsize() and still did not work.

Can someone tell me how to get the graph to span across 3 columns on the first row please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that methods like `plt.clf()`, `plt.bar()`, `plt.grid()`, and `plt.title()` all refer to the **current** figure. In your app, you have two `Graph_Item` instances, but only one `figure`. The `figure` reacts to the `size` of the `Graph_Item`, but since there is only one figure, the sizing is confused.
You can fix this by creating a new `figure` for each `Graph_Item` instance:

```
class Graph_Item(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(plt.figure(), **kwargs)
```

Then, in your `PlotCandlegraph()` method, you can use the saved `plt_num` to activate the correct `figure`:

```
def PlotCandlegraph(self, Data):
    plt_num = self.root.ids.Candlegraph.figure.number
    plt.figure(num=plt_num)
    plt.clf()
```

The `plt.figure()` method activates the figure with the specified `num` (or creates a new `figure`). See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figure)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Sorry about the simple question, I just had to read the documentation. I kept assuming the graph = self.root.ids.Candlegraph would refer to the intended plot but that's not it.